# Instance of keyword in Javascript

Tags: javascript

How does rect is an instance of Shape? Shape constructor is not on the prototype chain of rect.

```
rect.__proto__ : Rectangle.prototype
Rectangle.prototype : Object.prototype
```

---

```js
// Shape - superclass
function Shape() {
  this.x = 0;
  this.y = 0;
}

// superclass method
Shape.prototype.move = function(x, y) {
  this.x += x;
  this.y += y;
  console.info('Shape moved.');
};

// Rectangle - subclass
function Rectangle() {
  Shape.call(this); // call super constructor.
}

// subclass extends superclass
Rectangle.prototype = Object.create(Shape.prototype);
Rectangle.prototype.constructor = Rectangle;

var rect = new Rectangle();

console.log('Is rect an instance of Rectangle?', rect instanceof Rectangle); // true
console.log('Is rect an instance of Shape?', rect instanceof Shape); // true
rect.move(1, 1); // Outputs, 'Shape moved.'
```

What are the conditions for an object to be an instance of a Constructor?

Comment: It's not the *constructor* that's important, it's the *prototype*, and the `Shape` prototype is put on the prototype chain of `Rectangle` by the code you posted.

Comment: Tnx @Pointy, but there are two points that makes me vague.1,constructor property is changed 2, Object.create() doesn't link to Shape.prototype rather creates a copy of Shape prototype.

Comment: No, `Object.create(Shape.prototype)` creates a new object with `Shape.prototype` as its prototype link. It does not create a copy of the `Shape` prototype; [read the documentation.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/create)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I got it.

Here is the prototype chain.

```
rect__proto__: Rectangle. prototype
Rectangle.prototype.__proto__: Shape.prototype
```

Answer (score 1):

The instanceof operator tests that the constructor.prototype (Rectangle for example) is in object's prototype chain.

```
rect instanceof Rectangle
```

Is true because:

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(rect) === Rectangle.prototype
```

Please see more information here:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/instanceof

Also, you can trace this logic in the standard:
https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-function.prototype-@@hasinstance:

```
v instanceof F
```

evaluates as

```
F[@@hasInstance](v)
```

In the same time
https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-ordinaryhasinstance:

```
4. Let P be Get(C, "prototype")
7.a Let O be O.[[GetPrototypeOf]]().
7.d If SameValue(P, O) is true, return true.
```